# What triggered the Generalists?

Tags: discussion, badges

Overnight 33 people (including me) were awarded Generalist. I know this is a badge you can meet the requirements for yourself but not get because the site doesn't meet some requirement. Remind me what it was we didn't have but now do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [badge page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/badges/15/generalist):

```
 Provide non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.
```

However that doesn't give the full picture. We had to have >200 questions asked (perhaps even answered) in each of the top 40 tags. We only just passed that, and a short time later, we got this triggered. Woo!

Comment: Just checked the tags page. Our 40th most popular tag is buses, with 201 questions. So I think you're right - and thanks to whoever asked the 201st bus question!

Comment: Now I understand Mark's call to ask 'bus' questions!  Glad to have helped make this happen...

Comment: BTW [here is the data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/272302/how-close-to-recieving-the-generalist-badge) for those interested in their score.

Comment: Haha, I had 182 in buses, just needed it to reach 200 questions :)